# How can I search for a string across all comments in a PDF on Acrobat Web?

Tags: search

I have opened a PDF on [Acrobat Web](https://acrobat.adobe.com/). It has a few comments by others. How can I search for a string across all comments in a PDF on Acrobat Web?

[image]